# I can't run python game on ubuntu

Tags: python

This is a simple game coded in python the [source code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11645528/)

and when run it in ubuntu 14.04

I've got this error

```
    File "pong.py", line 18
self.canvas = canvas
   ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

how can I solve it thanks

Comment: I don´ t know where you got it, but there is a lot more wrong with it than just an indentation error. It lacks almost *all* indentation, but looking through the code, fixing (all) indentation won't fix it. Apart from that, it is written quite inefficiently for the section that I read through, even if it would work.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the statements have to be indented by 4 spaces like this

`def functionName():
    //some stuff here
    //other stuff here`

Looking at the error, this might be the problem.

Comment: 4 spaces is conventional, but as long as it is consequent, it works with any number of spaces.

Comment: But it says here : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Comment: That is a *Style Guide* for creating nicely readable code. Not that it doesn't work if you style it differently (respecting the indentation levels of course. I never ran into code with another indentation then 4 spaces, but it *does* work.

Answer (score 0):

This question should be in [Stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) not in AskUbuntu. Please migrate this question there.

*Apart from the above,*
it is a simple indentation error. You (or the coder) forgot to indent the lines in the function properly.

It should be like this:

*Example: Lines 17-28*

`def init(self,canvas,color,paddle,paddle1):
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.paddle = paddle
    self.paddle1 = paddle1
    self.id = canvas.create_oval(10,10,25,25, fill=color)
    self.canvas.move(self.id, 235,200)
    starts = [-3,3]
    random.shuffle(starts)
    self.x = starts[0]
    self.y = -3
    self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
    self.canvas_width = 500`

Do similarly for the other functions as well.

Comment: Not only those lines, almost the complete file has wrong indentation.

Comment: thanks adch99 i'v edit it but its not work :(

Comment: @MohammadAbuhassan ,Did you edit the entire file? And pls mind it  `def __init__(self,canvas,color,paddle,paddle1):` NOT `def init(self,canvas,color,paddle,paddle1):` the autoformatting doesn't seem to show it.

Comment: @adch99 got this error   File 'code' "pong.py", line 30
    paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
             ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: @MohammadAbuhassan, indent every line after the line containing `def` keyword till you encounter a blank line. Do this for the entire document.